# How to make a Views Filter criteria based on another language version existing?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

How to make a view that lists otherwise Finnish nodes but if there exists an English translation for the node, list that instead?

Filter criteria would be logically "Language: if there is an English translation, then that, else Finnish".

So when all nodes are Finnish, the list of the node titles would be (these are ordinals in Finnish, just for the example):

Ensimmäinen
Toinen
Kolmas
Neljäs
Viides

And then someone adds a translation to the second and third one, the list would become:

Ensimmäinen
Second <--- now links to the English translation of the node
Third <--- now links to the English translation of the node
Neljäs
Viides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: https://www.drupal.org/project/select_translation. It does exactly what I need and much more.